# How to encrypt an existing AWS S3 bucket which is used for hosting a static web page?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, encryption

I have an AWS S3 bucket which is used for hosting a static web page. As a result, the contents must be public, and enabling the encryption prevents to make the website available on the internet.

Is there a way on how to encrypt such AWS S3 bucket which is used for hosting a static web page?

Comment: I dont really get it. If its all publicly available data, then why do you want to encrypt it?

Comment: You can encrypt the bucket (storage) and expose the website using a CDN (CloudFront). But -  is there a purpose to encrypt the S3 storage when you want to make the content public anyway?

Answer (score 3):

Amazon S3 encryption is "encryption at rest". This means that it is encrypted when it is written to disk, but it is automatically decrypted when read from disk (and it is only read from disk if the requester has permission to access the object). This form of encryption prevents people from being able to read the data if they obtain access to the physical disk.

Therefore, if a bucket is configured to be Public, any requests for the objects will be accepted. When the data is read from disk it is decrypted and provided to the requester. The encryption is transparent -- nobody will ever see the encrypted form of the data when it is requested via Amazon S3.

Comment: When a bucket is Public, is there a point to encrypt the data?

Comment: If the whole bucket is public, then the data would be accessible via the Internet. So, no, there would not be any security benefit in encrypting the data at rest.